# ADT: Can i use the key used to sign debug versions for signing manual builds?

Tags: android, adt

I have a programm with an auto-updater and till now I deployed programm versions generated by the eclipse "Run" and "Debug" commands for my beta testers. (poor decision - as I know now)

Now I want do deploy versions that have been created by the "Export" command, but without the need for my testers to uninstall the app priror to installing the new version. To achieve this I would need to sign the apks created by the "Export" command with the key that is used for the automatic debug builds.

Is this possible? - If yes: how would i do that and where can I find the key that is used for this automatic builds?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the automatic debug key from ~/.android/debug.keystore . If you are using eclipse you can set the path to a custom keystore (if you are so inclined) from Windows->preference-> Android->Build. But the disadvantage of using the debug key is that 1)it is valid for 365 days only. 2) You can't publish your app to play store. and others which I can't recall.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html has all he details about signing your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! your link finally pointed me in the right direction: The path of the used keystore can be found out in ADT under: Windows > Preferences > Android > Build
The passwords are both "android"